# Regression that is continuous and differentiable at every value of X?

Tags: statistics, regression

I'm currently enrolled in a statistics course and we are studying regression models. What does it mean to develop a regression model that contains both a straight line in the regressor, as well as a quadratic model outside of the range for x where the model is continuous and differentiable at every value of x?

I'm not looking for an answer, but more of what is this question even asking? Should I create a value for $x_1$ = 1, for example, and then $x_2$ is both a quadratic that can take on any value besides 1?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. You better post the exercise word for word.

Comment: This is the question (verbatim): Write a regression model that includes a straight line in the regressor x for a given range of x and a quadratic model in x outside that range where the model is continuous and differentiable in every value of  x .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regression model is piecewise defined.

$$y_i=\begin{cases} b_0+b_1x_i+\epsilon_i \ \ \forall \ x_i\leq x^* \\  \\b_2+b_3x_i+b_4x_i^2+\epsilon_i  \ \ \forall \ x_i> x^*,\end{cases}$$

where $\epsilon_i$ is the error term.

Next the intersection of the two functions has to be calculated in order to find $x^*$. This can be done with the quadratic formula.

Comment: I have the quadratic set up as such : $(b_2-b_0) + (b_3-b_1)x_i+b_4(x_i)^2 = 0$. Do I use the quadratic formula assuming a = 1, b = 1, and c =1?

Comment: I got $x^*= -(b_3-b_1)+sqrt(frac((b_3-b_1)-(b_2-b_0)(b_4))(2(b_2-b_0))$

Comment: The equation of your first comment is right. For $x^*$ I´ve got another expression. For instance, $(b_3-b_1)$ is squared under the square root.

Comment: That's right -- I missed the squared term and the constant 4 multiplied by $(b_2-b_0)(b_4)$ in the numerator. Thank you!

Comment: Now you are right. You are welcome.